# How to make a content to second row? I tried \thread, not working

Tags: tables, tabularx

I am having so much trouble in making a table.

I know that `\thread` about the split the content in a cell into 2 row. But not successful.

Basically, I want to draw a table like this below:

[image]

The output of mine:

[image]

I am using

```
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}Xllrr}
```

My Full MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside]{book}

\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{makecell, multirow, tabularx}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\small\bfseries} % for bold in table using \small
\renewcommand\theadgape{}
\usepackage[svgnames, table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{hhline, boldline}
\usepackage{seqsplit, caption} %for table spacing to second row
\usepackage{booktabs, ragged2e} % Use booktabs rules and get rid of vertical rules, ragged2e to ragged text
\usepackage{siunitx} %for table spacing to second row
\usepackage{threeparttable} %to add footnote below table
\usepackage{tabulary}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h!]
\centering
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}Xllrr}

    % \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}Xrrrrrr}


    \toprule
    & & & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Cholestrrol Levellll}} \\
     \cmidrule{4-5}
     & &  & \thead{{\textbf{Equal}} \\ \textbf{variances} \\ \textbf{assumed}}
     & \thead{{\textbf{Equal}} \\ \textbf{variances not} \\ \textbf{assumed}}\\
\midrule

    \multicolumn{1}{l}{Levene's Test for Equality of Variances} & F 
    & & 0.314 &   \\
    & Sig. & & 0.579 & \\

\midrule

    \multicolumn{1}{l}{t-test for Equality of Means} & t
    & & 2.428 & 2.428   \\
    & df & & 38 & 34.886 \\
    & Sig. (2-tailed) &  & 0.579 & 0.64273\\
    & 95\% Confidence &  Lower & 0.579 & 0.64273\\

\bottomrule

\end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The problems come from the `\multicolumn{1}{l}{...` in the leftmost column (which is of `X` type). Things look much better if you replace them by `\multicolumn{1}{X}{...`, or just use no `\multicolumn` there at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The left-most column is "special", it is of the `X` type, meaning it adjusts is size to make the title as wide as you want it to be. Now, when you use

```
\multicolumn{1}{l}{Levene's Test for Equality of Variances}
```

and a second statement of that sort, you kill that poor `X` column. This makes David Carlisle unhappy, and the table go berserk. If you remove these `\multicolumn`s in the first column, you get

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside]{book}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{makecell, multirow, tabularx}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\small\bfseries} % for bold in table using \small
\renewcommand\theadgape{}
\usepackage{booktabs, ragged2e} % Use booktabs rules and get rid of vertical rules, ragged2e to ragged text

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h!]
\centering
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}Xllrr}

    % \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}Xrrrrrr}


    \toprule
    & & & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Cholestrrol Levellll}} \\
     \cmidrule{4-5}
     & &  & \thead{{\textbf{Equal}} \\ \textbf{variances} \\ \textbf{assumed}}
     & \thead{{\textbf{Equal}} \\ \textbf{variances not} \\ \textbf{assumed}}\\
\midrule

    Levene's Test for Equality of Variances
    & F 
    & & 0.314 &   \\
    & Sig. & & 0.579 & \\

\midrule

    t-test for Equality of Means
    & t
    & & 2.428 & 2.428   \\
    & df & & 38 & 34.886 \\
    & Sig. (2-tailed) &  & 0.579 & 0.64273\\
    & 95\% Confidence &  Lower & 0.579 & 0.64273\\

\bottomrule

\end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

In general, a `\multicolumn{1}{<type>}{...}` makes only sense if `type` deviates from the type specified in the header. However, in your example, the only entries of the `X` column were `\multicolumn` entries.

Comment: Thanks. Brillant. Is there a way to make `second column` similar to `first column` too? For example `95\% Confidence Interval of the Differene`?

Comment: @aan You can have more than one `X` column, if that's what you are asking.

Comment: @aan Or do you want to make the second column `>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}l`? (I do not understand the question.)

Comment: Thanks. I got your answer. I tried `\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}XXlrr}` works well. However, a second question came out which is: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/515754/how-to-make-a-small-blank-line-row-in-a-table-because-my-content-overlap-the