# How to make a small blank line (row) in a table? Because my content overlap the \bottomrule

Tags: tables, tabularx

This is a follow up link question to [How to make a content into 2 row](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/515749/how-to-make-a-content-to-second-row-i-tried-thread-not-working/515750?noredirect=1#comment1304102_515750)

[image]

Basically, I want to have a small gap in `blue line` below and also do not touch the bottomrule

[image]

My full MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside]{book}

\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{makecell, multirow, tabularx}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\small\bfseries} % for bold in table using \small
\renewcommand\theadgape{}
\usepackage[svgnames, table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{hhline, boldline}
\usepackage{seqsplit, caption} %for table spacing to second row
\usepackage{booktabs, ragged2e} % Use booktabs rules and get rid of vertical rules, ragged2e to ragged text
\usepackage{siunitx} %for table spacing to second row
\usepackage{threeparttable} %to add footnote below table
\usepackage{tabulary}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h!]
\centering
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}XXlrr}

    % \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}Xrrrrrr}


    \toprule
    & & & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Cholestrrol Levellll}} \\
     \cmidrule{4-5}
     & &  & \thead{{\textbf{Equal}} \\ \textbf{variances} \\ \textbf{assumed}}
     & \thead{{\textbf{Equal}} \\ \textbf{variances not} \\ \textbf{assumed}}\\
\midrule

\multirow{3}{=}{Levene's Test for Equality of Variances}

    & F 
    & & 0.314 &   \\
    & Sig. & & 0.579 & \\

\midrule

\multirow{5}{=}{t-test for Equality of Means}


    & t
    & & 2.428 & 2.428   \\
    & df & & 38 & 34.886 \\
    & Sig. (2-tailed) &  & 0.579 & 0.64273\\
    & Mean Difference &  & 0.579 & 0.64273\\
    & Std. Error Difference &  & 0.579 & 0.64273\\
    & \multirow{1.2}{=}{95\% Confidence of Interval of the Difference}  &  Lower & 0.579 & 0.64273\\
    & &  Upper & 0.579 & 0.64273\\
\bottomrule

\end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat Sorry, I forget. Too rush. Thanks for reminding, edited done

Comment: If nothing else helps, you could add an empty row, `& &   &  & \\ `  before `\bottomrule`. On the other hand, you are loading `makecell`. Have you tried to use it for the two-row entry?

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat Thanks. I tried `& & & & \\` have a very big gap. I am not sure how to use `makecell` and `two-row entry`. Could you give a simple example?

Comment: Interesting. On my updated TeXLive 2019 installation I do not get a big gap. Do you have an up-to-date installation? (I compile with pdflatex, how do you compile?)

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat . thanks. I am using `Overleaf`.

Comment: Try adding a [+1.4ex] or something just after the last \\ (@Schrödinger'scat ... (S)He possibly using your approach in the original document and not the MWE...)

Comment: @koleygr. It works. What does `[+1.4ex]` mean? `adding in 1.4mm`?

Comment: OMG. Overleaf. `[+1.4ex]` means "add a space of `1.4ex`. `ex` (and `em`) are so-called extensible units, they scale with the font size.

Comment: @aan ... it adds some space that is 1.2 of the fontsize height (something close to it actually) See here : https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/8260/120578

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat Oveleaf is easy to use without need compiler and can share it. Why you said OMG?

Comment: @koleygr Thanks, the link is superb!

Comment: Welcome @aan ... Happy TeXing...

Comment: Because I have seen so many examples where users rediscover bugs that have been solved ages ago. Overleaf uses a *very* old installation. Plus it "compresses" error messages. What I want to say is that if you are happy with it, that's fine, but I would never want to be at their mercy.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat. Can you explain more the overleaf `compresses error mesages` meaning? Do you mean it combine a lot errors together?

Comment: I'd actually recommend https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/4244/194703, where it is correctly stated that `1ex` is the height of the letter `x` (and to the best of my knowledge *not* "1.2 of the fontsize height" @koleygr ...).

Comment: No, by default  it just does not give you the full error message. Let me stress that I never used overleaf myself but I had more than enough situations in which users uploaded codes with errors, and claimed that they did not get any message. I was told that overleaf suppresses error messages. Anyway, this code seems to be an example of something where the output of overleaf differs from the one you get on an updated TeX installation. What that means is that, once overleaf update their packages, you may get a different result.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat Thanks. I got your meaning. Can you have a look https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/515762/avoid-a-words-being-break-unevenly-for-example-diff-erent if you have time? Another problem occured again, never ending

Answer (score 1):

I'd do some redesign to avoid the large blank areas in the table. Probably the following suits your needs:

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside]{book}

\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{makecell, multirow, tabularx}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\small\bfseries} % for bold in table using \small
\renewcommand\theadgape{}
\usepackage[svgnames, table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{hhline, boldline}
\usepackage{seqsplit, caption} %for table spacing to second row
\usepackage{booktabs, ragged2e} % Use booktabs rules and get rid of vertical rules, ragged2e to ragged text
\usepackage{siunitx} %for table spacing to second row
\usepackage{threeparttable} %to add footnote below table
\usepackage{tabulary}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h!]
\centering
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{>{\quad}Xlrr}
    \toprule
     & & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Cholestrrol Levellll}} \\
     \cmidrule{3-4}
       &  & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\thead{Equal variances}} \\ 
       &  & \thead{assumed} & \thead{not \\ assumed}\\
\midrule
\multicolumn{4}{@{}l}{Levene's Test for Equality of Variances}\\
     F    & & 0.314 &   \\
     Sig. & & 0.579 & \\
\midrule
\multicolumn{4}{@{}l}{t-test for Equality of Means}\\
     t  & & 2.428 & 2.428   \\
     df & & 38 & 34.886 \\
     Sig. (2-tailed) &  & 0.579 & 0.64273\\
     Mean Difference &  & 0.579 & 0.64273\\
     Std. Error Difference &  & 0.579 & 0.64273\\
     \multirow{2}{=}{95\% Confidence of Interval of the Difference}  &  Lower & 0.579 & 0.64273\\
     &  Upper & 0.579 & 0.64273\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: thanks. Is very nicely table too. You using `\multicolumn{4}{@{}l}{\textbf{t-test for Equality of Means}}`. which is `@{}l`, can give more explanation in this?

Comment: @aan: `l` to left align the text that is used inside of the `\multicolumn` command. `@{}` is used to remove the small horizontal space that is automatically added to the left and right of every table cell  (this length is called `\tabcolsep`, default value is `6pt`). If you prefer, you can of course also use `\multicolumn{4}{l}{\textbf{t-test for Equality of Means}}` instead.